# Flask with two databases (mysql and mongo)

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, flask

Is it possible in Python Flask to connect to 2 databases, one mysql and one mongo?

This is for an e-commerce app where the users are stored in mysql and the products in mongo.

If yes, can you give me an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is possible. A good starting point for an example would be your setup code for one database.

Comment: I don't have any setup code because now I am looking what technologies to use. This is why I request an example, I want to try that example myself.

Comment: Unluckily that is not how SO works. Here, you give your code and a specific problem with it.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this. Thank you for the confirmation that it is possible.